# Install php_trader.dll in WAMP Server (3.0.6 x64 ) on Windows

Tags: php, wamp, pecl

For installing PHP Trader extension in my local WAMP 3.0.6 on Windows 10 Pro x64, I did the following steps:

1. Downloaded **php_trader-0.4.0-7.2-nts-vc15-x64.zip** from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/trader/0.4.0/ .
2. Placed the **php_trader.dll** in wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext folder.
3. In my php.ini, accessible from WAMP notification icon, added a line as: `extension=php_trader.dll`.
4. Restarted all services from WAMP notification icon. But PHP Error Log shows the following:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
d:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_trader.dll - The specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0`

I wonder what am I doing wrong here.

**UPDATE**

I downloaded the thread-safe x64 `trader 0.4.0` DLL from https://pecl.php.net/package/trader/0.4.0/windows, and its now working.

Cheers

Comment: I downloaded the thread-safe x64 `trader 0.4.0` DLL from [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/trader/0.4.0/windows), and its now working.

Comment: there is no DLL available for the link you provided now!

Comment: the Latest Tarball mentioned under the description on the same page is link to the download page, which is this one: https://pecl.php.net/get/trader

Comment: ty saw that already, but there is no DLL file in that archive

Answer (score 5):

As stated by others, You might need to download `Thread safe` version:

- https://pecl.php.net/package/trader

**Click "DLL" under downloads column, the specific PHP 7.Xversion you use**

1) put the .dll file in `wamp\bin\php\php7.X\ext`

2) Left click on WAMP > PHP > PHP.ini > add this line:

```
extension=trader
```

3) Restart WAMP

Comment: why I can't see "DLL" under the downloads column!?

Comment: The only post, that helped me after days of trial.